# How do I customise anchor tag to call an ActiveX control to open a link in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery

We have a tool that generates a web page. In this webpage , there are certain hyperlinks that should be opened in Chrome. Please note that the tool always runs in IE  and ActiveX objects are allowed.

The work around i came up with was to use jQuery  to attach a click handler to the hyperlink and call a function that would open this link in Chrome. Below is my script and I am unable to find out why this is not working.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .link1 {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.link1').bind("click", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        shell.run("chrome http://www.google.com");
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="item">
    <a title="" class="link1" href="#">chromeopen</a>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y question. Why do you need to open something *specifically* in Chrome? I would assume it's because whatever you're trying to do is not supported in IE. As such I would ask about that instead of using a massively outdated technology, with various security issues, such as ActiveX.

Comment: Hi Rory , unfortunately  one of the  websites that we have  functions only in Chrome while the landing page only in IE.

Comment: That's my point; that is the issue you should be spending your time fixing, not using some hacky workaround to open specific pages in different browsers

Comment: Ideally yes , we are in the midst of a transition and will need both the systems  and the hack if it works would serve as a work around until lthen .